# White flashing in between pages with large angular application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome

Since a couple of weeks I'm experiencing a white flash in between transitions of my angular >=1.5 application. It uses `HTML5` mode.

I made a small GIF to demonstrate what is happening, I can remember seeing this in the past and solving this with `backface-visibility` set to `hidden`, but for some reason that CSS prop seems to have disappeared.

[image]

This is a full SPA, so it shouldn't be doing this weird rendering I would assume. The browser I'm testing with is Google Chrome `51.0.2704.103 (Official Build) (64-bit)`.